# ¿Qué otras palabras existen en español cuyo singular se haya formado partiendo del plural?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

En Sevilla y otras ciudades se conocen a [los *seises*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seises) como el grupo de niños

> [..] que, vestidos lujosamente con traje antiguo de seda azul y blanca, bailan y cantan tocando las castañuelas en la catedral de Sevilla, y en algunas otras, en determinadas festividades del año.

El texto citado es en realidad parte de la definición de *[seise](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XU5F6YP)*. El nombre hace referencia a que el grupo estaba formado por seis niños (aunque en Sevilla en la actualidad son diez). En la etimología de la palabra se menciona:

> Sing. formado a partir del pl. *seises*, y este de *seis*.

Es decir, que primero se originó el nombre del grupo ("los seises") y a partir de ahí se formó *seise* (y no *seis*) como el singular para referirse a un niño concreto del grupo.

Una vez compartida esta curiosidad, vamos con otra pregunta de pura curiosidad: ¿existen más sustantivos en español cuyo singular se haya formado a partir del plural?

Nota: busco palabras que tengan voces distintas para el singular y el plural, eso excluye casos como *gafa/gafas*, *pantalón/pantalones* y similares, en los que ambas voces se pueden usar para el singular.

Comment: Buscando en el Dirae "sing. formado" me salen tres: seise, cuis y aborigen; este último formado del plural en latín

Comment: @blonfu entiendo entonces que "aborigen" no entraría como respuesta dado que el plural sería de otro idioma. Eso nos deja a "seise" y "cuis" como únicos ejemplos válidos salvo que el DLE registre más casos que no aparezcan en la búsqueda de "sing. formado".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Va uno regional: en Argentina le decimos **[cuis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bc7rcBp)** a un animalito que todos llaman de manera distinta, y eso porque de *cuy* se derivó el plural irregular *cuises*. (Si hay que agregar sólo una “s” tenemos tendencia a hacerla “ses”: un pie, dos pieses, etc.)

Comment: Nótese que *cuis* se pronuncia [kwis] mientras que *cuy* se pronuncia [kuj], así que también hicimos un cambio en el acento.

Comment: Me ha resultado una respuesta entrañable, porque hará uno 15 años tuvimos una cobaya (que entiendo es el "animalito que todos llaman de manera distinta") y el ruido que hacía decíamos que era "cui, cui". No sabía que esa onomatopeya hubiera dado lugar a un sustantivo para el mismo animal.

Comment: Pues lo de *cuis* yo lo he oído por aquí (País Vasco) también